# Set value in TextField from a useState object when maping

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im trying to set the value in a TextField from Material UI to a useState. My problem is that the useState is set in the same useEffekt.

My use state is going to have this format:

```
{nameOfExercice: aNumber, 
 nameOfExercice: aNumber, 
 nameOfExercice: aNumber,}
```

Where the amount of exercises, the name of the exercises and the number will come from a database, so I don't "know" how many attributes the object will have.

My Text field will look like this. Where formData is the useState.

```
 <TextField
          id={element.name}
          label={element.name}
          inputProps={{ min: 1, max: 3, type: "number" }}
          value={formData[element.name] ? formData[element.name] : 0}
          onChange={changeForm}
        />
```

My problem is that sense they are run in the same useEffect the formData is not set yet, but I need the values from it as a reference. I assume I could use a second useEffect that will run when formData changes but I would like to avoid this.

What can I do?